# Stored procedures prefixed with sp_MSdel<TableName>, sp_MSins<TableName>, sp_MSupd<TableName>

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I noticed in the database I manage a bunch of stored procedures for delete, insert, update prefixed with sp_MSdel, sp_MSins and sp_MSupd.

Does anyone know what tool creates these stored procedures?

Here is the source code of the update stored procedure (I replaced the table name and the field names):

```
create procedure [dbo].[sp_MSupd_dboTableName]
        @c1 int = NULL,
        @c2 nvarchar(50) = NULL,
        @c3 nvarchar(50) = NULL,
        @c4 nvarchar(50) = NULL,
        @c5 nvarchar(50) = NULL,
        @c6 datetime = NULL,
        @c7 datetime = NULL,
        @pkc1 int = NULL,
        @bitmap binary(1)
as
begin  
update [dbo].[TableName] set
        [field2] = case substring(@bitmap,1,1) & 2 when 2 then @c2 else [EmpIdentif] end,
        [field3] = case substring(@bitmap,1,1) & 4 when 4 then @c3 else [Pid] end,
        [field4] = case substring(@bitmap,1,1) & 8 when 8 then @c4 else [AdUsername] end,
        [field5] = case substring(@bitmap,1,1) & 16 when 16 then @c5 else [EmployeeID] end,
        [field6] = case substring(@bitmap,1,1) & 32 when 32 then @c6 else [AdAccountsRegisteredTimestamp] end,
        [field7] = case substring(@bitmap,1,1) & 64 when 64 then @c7 else [EmployeeIdsRegisteredTimestamp] end
where [id] = @pkc1
if @@rowcount = 0
    if @@microsoftversion>0x07320000
        exec sp_MSreplraiserror 20598
end
GO
```

Comment: Replication creates those from what I recall

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those procedures are created when SQL Server Replication (Transactional Replication) is configured for a table in the database. See [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/transactional/transactional-articles-specify-how-changes-are-propagated?view=sql-server-ver15#default-and-custom-stored-procedures) for more info.